# Como faço essa consulta usando o laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-eloquent

SELECT DATE AS dt,COUNT(1) AS total FROM activities where activity_worktype IN('Ativação','Remanejamento Externo') AND subject = 'activity_completed'
GROUP BY DATE

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
ActivityWorktype::select([DB::raw('date as dt'), DB::raw('count(1) as total')])
    ->whereIn(['Ativação','Remanejamento Externo'])
    ->where('subject', 'activity_completed')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('dt'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).